# Writing a Custom Key JsonConverter for Dictionary

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0, system.text.json

In ASP.NET Core 6, I am trying to write a `JsonConverter` for a type `DateRange` that is only 2 `DateTime` - `Begin` and `End` - and they are the key for a `Dictionary<DateRange, List<myObject>>` but it keeps throwing an exception saying it has written too much or too little data..

Here is my `DateRangeConverter`:

```
public class DateRangeConverter : JsonConverter<DateRange>
{
    public override DateRange? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        reader.Read(); // Skip over key
        var begin = ReadDateTime(ref reader);
        var end = ReadDateTime(ref reader);
        return new DateRange { Begin = begin, End = end };
    }

    public override DateRange ReadAsPropertyName(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        reader.Read(); // Skip over key
        var begin = ReadDateTime(ref reader);
        var end = ReadDateTime(ref reader);
        return new DateRange { Begin = begin, End = end };
    }

    public override void WriteAsPropertyName(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateRange value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartObject();
        writer.WritePropertyName("Begin");
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.Begin.ToString("o"));
        writer.WritePropertyName("End");
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.End.ToString("o"));
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateRange value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteString("Begin",value.Begin);
        writer.WriteString("End", value.End);
    }

    private void WriteDateTime(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateRange value)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
    }

    private void WriteDateTime(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value)
    {
        writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("o"));
    }

    private DateTime ReadDateTime(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
    {
        var year = reader.GetInt32();
        var month = reader.GetByte();
        var day = reader.GetByte();
        var hour = reader.GetByte();
        var minute = reader.GetByte();
        var second = reader.GetByte();
        var millisecond = reader.GetInt32();
        var kind = (DateTimeKind)reader.GetByte();
        return new DateTime(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond, kind);
    }
}
```

I would hope it serializes an object to JSON.

Comment: You can help other people's chances of helping you by posting the exact error message that you get and by indicating how and where it occurs. --- Anyway, without having spent too much time reviewing your code, it seems odd to me that the reading and writing of `DateTime` values is asymmetrical: you emit a string when writing but expect discrete numbers when reading.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError well the error is The converter 'Microservices.Common.JsonConverters.DateRangeConverter' wrote too much or not enough. Path: $.Data.due to Stack trace   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonException_SerializationConverterWrite(JsonConverter converter)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.DictionaryOfTKeyTValueConverter`3.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonDictionaryConverter`3.OnTryWrite

Comment: 1) Might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve] as suggested in [ask]?  2) Is `DateRange` from [`Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Work.WebApi`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.work.webapi.daterange?view=azure-devops-dotnet)?  Does if override `ToString()`, `Equals()` or `eGetHashCode()`?  3) Do you have control over your JSON format (so the converter only needs to round-trip) or do you need to conform to some pre-existing JSON format that you cannot change?  4) If you cannot change the JSON format, please [edit] your question to share a sample.